# Moderator analysis for subgroups with the metafor package

Tags: r, metafor

I have a dataset with 2 moderators, `model` and `mechanism` which have 3 and 5 levels respectively. Separate meta-regression with each moderator using the `rma()` function in the *metafor* package revealed that both of them significantly influence the summary effect. However, fitting additive model with both moderators resulted in values for groups that do not exist, which i find difficult to interpret. So I decided to perform subgroup analysis for `model` with consequent meta-regression with the moderator `mechanism`. However, although I can run:

```
run.5 = rma(yi = es, vi = var, data = agg.es.mod, subset = model == "IR")
```

I don't know how to run moderator analysis with `mechanism` for this subgroup. Is it possible at all to do this in *metafor*? Such function would be highly useful, because if not, I guess one must subdivide the data and run separate meta-analyses?

Comment: What do you mean with "resulted in values for groups that do not exist"? Also, have you read this? http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:multiple_factors_interactions

Comment: Thank you for the link. I had read it several times, indeed. The summary table via "addmargins()" shows me that there is 0 study in 2 combinations of moderators. However, the model returned estimates, p ... for these combinations and i could also plot them.

By the way, I really appreciate the efforts you have put in the metafor package. It has been a great great help for me and certainly may others. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can still estimate main effects, even if certain combinations never occur.